# WhatsApp client for Mac

Tags: macos, whatsapp

Are there any good WhatsApp clients for macOS?

I have tried two:

1. Official WhatsApp MAS app - tends to get unresponsive if
   there is a lot of unread messages or sometimes for no apparent
   reasons at all.
2. Franz - leaks memory like crazy, 1,5 Gb within a day.

This is probably a long shot, since Facebook does not provide WhatsApp API unless you are a well established / known corporation, so all solutions are basically a wrapper around a web app, but maybe somebody got it right.

PS: paid app is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use  [ChatMate for WhatsApp](https://chatmate.io/):

- non-free
- has dark mode

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a pretty good app! Thanks for the suggestion.